# esp8266 restarting.maybe needs yield

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I'm having some problems with the esp8266 201. I've powered it with a (more than enough) power supply, it keeps restarting itself.

Even if the esp8266 sometimes connects to the Internet and Cayenne discovers it,then it gets offline and online again. Some guys told me to use yields, but I don't have any idea how to use them.

The code below is used to connect to Cayenne and add some sensors to it. This happens before the yield.

```
 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>   //SoftwareSerial library required for Arduino  communication with the Grove RFID reader and the Grove Serial MP3 player
 #include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
 #include "CayenneDefines.h"
 #include "CayenneWiFiClient.h"

 char token[] = "";        //Cayenne authentication token. This should be obtained from the Cayenne Dashboard.
 // Your network name and password.
 char ssid[] = "";
 char password[] = "";             

 SoftwareSerial mp3(2,3);                                  //Grove Serial MP3 Player is connected to Digital Pins 2 and 3
 SoftwareSerial rfid(10,11);                               //Grove 125kHz  RFID reader is connected to Digital Pins 10 and 11 (Note: lower pins may not work with this board)

 //Global Variables
 int rfidValue = 0;                                        //rfidValue: used to store the value obtained from the RFID tag   
 int vPin6 = 0;                                            //vPin6: is associated with Virtual Pin 6 on the Cayenne Dashboard - activated when a person is detected by the sensors.
 int vPin7 = 0;                                            //vPin7: is associated with Virtual Pin 7 on the Cayenne Dashboard - activated when the person fails to identify themselves.
 unsigned long start_Time;                                 //start_Time: is used in various time related events (logs the start time)
 unsigned long stop_Time;                                  //stop_Time: is used in various time related events (logs the stop time)
 unsigned long time_Diff = 0;                              //time_Diff: is used in various time related events (is used to record the time elapsed from      start time to stop time)
 boolean keyMessagePlayed=false;                           //keyMessagePlayed: helps to prevent a message from replaying repeatedly when a person is detected.
 boolean waitingForKey = true;                             //waitingForKey: is used to identify if we are still waiting for a person to present a valid key or not
 int songNumber = -1;                                      //songNumber is a variable used to hold the song number to play (from the playlist on the SD card on the MP3 player)

 /*===============================setup()============================================================================================================================= */
 void setup(){
   delay(2500);                                            //Delay for 2.5 seconds to allow the Grove MP3 player to initialise
   mp3.begin(9600);                                        //Establish a communication link with the Grove MP3 player
   rfid.begin(9600);                                       //Establish a communication link with the Grove 125 kHz RFID reader
   Serial.begin(9600);                                     //Establish a communication link with my computer (via the Serial monitor) - for debugging purposes.
   Cayenne.begin(token, ssid, password);                                        //Establish a communication link with the Cayenne Server - the token must match that in the Cayenne Dashboard
   setVolume(28);                                          //Set the volume of the MP3 player to 28 (Range = 0 to 31, whereby 31 is maximum volume)
   setPlayMode(0x00);                                      //Configure the MP3 player to play the MP3 file ONCE only (per request).
 }

 /*===============================loop()============================================================================================================================= */
 void loop(){
   Cayenne.run();                                          //Synchronise with the Cayenne Server

   if(vPin6&&!vPin7){                                      //Only progress if Virtual Pin 6 (Person detection) is ACTIVATED but ONLY when Virtual Pin 7 (Intruder alert) has NOT already been activated.
     if(!keyMessagePlayed){                                //This ensures that the message is played only ONCE when a person has been detected.
  playSong(1);                                        //Play the following message on the Grove MP3 player: "Place your keys on the mat"
       keyMessagePlayed=true;                              //keyMessagePlayed is changed to TRUE once the message has been played.
     }

      /*This section requests the Arduino to look out for the person's keys, and returns TRUE when a successful identification is made.
  * It returns FALSE if the person fails to put their keys on the Mat within 10 seconds , OR if the person cannot be identified by the Arduino (e.g. Wrong code)
  * If a person has been successfully identified/verified, it will play a welcome message, and switch off the "Person Detection Trigger", which will then 
  * be used as a method to switch off the Security scanning process.
  * If a person fails to be identified within 10 seconds, the person is notified that they have been detected, and an Alarm will sound.
  * Virtual Pin 7 (Intruder Alert) will be ACTIVATED - which will be used as a Trigger within Cayenne to notify me of an Intruder (via Email or SMS).
  */
if(listenForKeys()){                                 
  //TRUE = Person Identified within 10 seconds
  playSong(songNumber);                               //Play message "Welcome Home - Scott"
  vPin6 = 0;                                          //Deactivate the "Person Detection" virtual pin (6).
  keyMessagePlayed=false;                             //Reset the keyMessagePlayed variable for future detections.
} else {
  //FALSE = Person not identified within 10 seconds
  playSong(2);                                        //Play message on Grove MP3 player : "Your presence has been detected"
  delay(4000);                                        //A FOUR second delay is required to allow the message to play, before the alarm sounds.
  playSong(3);                                        //Sound the ALARM by playing song 2 on the Grove MP3 player. Song numbers are determined by the order they have been written to the SD card.
  delay(8000);                                        //An EIGHT second delay allows the alarm to sound for 8 seconds.
  playSong(99);                                       //Playing a non-existing track essentially STOPS the MP3 player.
  vPin7=1;                                            //ACTIVATE Virtual Pin 7 - Intruder Detected
  keyMessagePlayed=false;                             //Reset the keyMessagePlayed variable for future detections.
}

upDateCayenne();                                      //Update the Cayenne Dashboard with any changes made to the virtual pins (6 or 7). This method can be found below.
   } 
 }     


 /*=writeToMP3 function====================================================================================================================================================== 
  * is used to simplify the process of sending commands to the Grove MP3            */
 void writeToMP3(byte MsgLEN, byte A, byte B, byte C, byte D, byte E, byte F){
   byte codeMsg[] = {MsgLEN, A,B,C,D,E,F};
   mp3.write(0x7E);                                        //Start Code for every command = 0x7E
   for(byte i = 0; i<MsgLEN+1; i++){
     mp3.write(codeMsg[i]);                                //Send the rest of the command to the GROVE MP3 player
   }
 }

 /*=setVolume function====================================================================================================================================================== 
  * is used to simplify the process of setting the Volume on the Grove MP3 player
  * Volume range = 00 (muted) to 31 (max volume)
  */
 void setVolume(byte Volume){                                                
   byte tempVol = constrain(Volume, 0, 31);                //Ensure the Volume does not extend beyond the MP3 player's limits
   writeToMP3(0x03, 0xA7, tempVol, 0x7E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00); 
 }

 /*=setPlayMode function====================================================================================================================================================== 
  * is used to simplify the process of setting up the play Mode on the Grove MP3 player
  * playMode options:
       *      0x00 = Single song - played only once ie. not repeated.  (default)
  *      0x01 = Single song - cycled ie. repeats over and over.
  *      0x02 = All songs - cycled 
  *      0x03 = play songs randomly   
  */
 void setPlayMode(byte playMode){     
   writeToMP3(0x03, 0xA9, playMode, 0x7E, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);  
 }

 /*=playSong function====================================================================================================================================================== 
  * is used to simplify the process of playing a specific track on the SD card of the Grove MP3 player.
  * The track number is determined by the order in which the songs were written to the SD card. 
  * Best to name the tracks in sequence, e.g.  0000_Song0.mp3   ,   0001_Song1.mp3    etc etc.
  * And also best to copy them one by one to the SD card from Song 0 to Song x.
  */
 void playSong(byte songNum){                             
   writeToMP3(0x04, 0xA0, 0x00, songNum, 0x7E, 0x00, 0x00);            
 }

 /*=listenForKeys function====================================================================================================================================================== 
  * is used to identify the person detected.
  * The Arduino will wait a maximum of 10 seconds for the person to place their RFID tag near the Grove RFID reader antenna.
  * This example shows two RFID tag values that will be accepted.
  * This method also prints the RFID tag value to the Serial monitor - for debugging purposes.
  */
 boolean listenForKeys(){
   //reset some variables every time this function is called.
   songNumber = -1;
   start_Time = millis();
   time_Diff = 0;
   waitingForKey = true;
   rfidValue=0; 

   //Wait for a valid RFID tag for a maximum of 10 seconds
   while(time_Diff<10000 && waitingForKey){
      Cayenne.run();                                       //Make sure to stay in contact with the Cayenne Server while waiting for the RFID tag.
 stop_Time = millis();                          
 time_Diff = stop_Time - start_Time;                  //Measure the time elapsed.

 //If an RFID tag is detected by the Grove RFID reader, it will transmit a series of numbers related to the Tag ID.
 if(rfid.available()){
    while(rfid.available()){                          //Make sure to read all of the numbers transmitted by the Grove RFID reader
      rfidValue += rfid.read();                       //You could employ a method to extract the exact RFID Tag ID - however just adding each number received -  produced a unique number that I could use to identify the person.
      delay(1);                                       //A small delay between reads - ensures you get all of the numbers from the RFID reader in one go.
    }
    Serial.println("RFID VALUE:");
    Serial.println(rfidValue);                        //Print the Unique RFID Tag value to the Serial monitor - useful for debugging


    //If a person has an RFID tag that can be identified in this list, then play a personalised message for that person.
    switch(rfidValue){
      case 628:                                       //Person #1 has a Tag that generates an rfidValue of 628.
        songNumber=4;                                 //File#4 (or message number 4) on the Grove MP3 player will be played when this person is detected.
        waitingForKey = false;                        //setting the "waitingForKey" variable to FALSE - will allow us to break out of the while loop (instead of waiting for a full 10 seconds).
        break;
      case 651:                                       //Person #2 has a Tag that generates an rfidValue of 651.
        songNumber=5;                                 //File#5 (or message number 5) on the Grove MP3 player will be played when this person is detected.
        waitingForKey = false;                        //setting the "waitingForKey" variable to FALSE - will allow us to break out of the while loop (instead of waiting for a full 10 seconds).
        break;
      case 694:                                       //Person #3 has a Tag that generates an rfidValue of 694.
        songNumber=6;                                 //File#6 (or message number 6) on the Grove MP3 player will be played when this person is detected.
        waitingForKey = false;                        //setting the "waitingForKey" variable to FALSE - will allow us to break out of the while loop (instead of waiting for a full 10 seconds).
        break;
      case 658:                                       //Person #4 has a Tag that generates an rfidValue of 658.
        songNumber=7;                                 //File#7 (or message number 7) on the Grove MP3 player will be played when this person is detected.
        waitingForKey = false;                        //setting the "waitingForKey" variable to FALSE - will allow us to break out of the while loop (instead of waiting for a full 10 seconds).
        break;
      case 677:                                       //Person #5 has a Tag that generates an rfidValue of 677.
        songNumber=8;                                 //File#8 (or message number 8) on the Grove MP3 player will be played when this person is detected.
        waitingForKey = false;                        //setting the "waitingForKey" variable to FALSE - will allow us to break out of the while loop (instead of waiting for a full 10 seconds).
        break;
      default:
        waitingForKey = true;                         //If a person has not been identified, keep waiting for the key/tag until the times runs out.
        break;
    }
}
   }

   /* If we are still waiting for an RFID tag (key) at this point, then we were unsuccessful in identifying the person within 10 seconds.
    *  Returning FALSE - will sound the alarm, and will activate Virtual Pin 7 (Intruder Alert).
    *  Returning TRUE - means that we have identified the person who triggered the sensors, and can therefore relax, and turn OFF the Security sensors.
    */
   if(waitingForKey){                                  
return false;
   } else {
     return true;
   }
      }

 /*=upDateCayenne function====================================================================================================================================================== 
  * This function will transmit the values of vPin6 and vPin7 to the Cayenne Dashboard's Virtual Pin 6 and 7 (respectively).
  * This will help the Cayenne Server to keep up to date with the status of each variable.
  */
 void upDateCayenne() {
   Cayenne.virtualWrite(V6, vPin6);
   delay(50);
   Cayenne.virtualWrite(V7, vPin7);
   delay(50);
 }

 /*=CAYENNE_IN(V6) function====================================================================================================================================================== 
  * This will update the Arduino's vPin6 variable to the same value as Virtual Pin 6 on the Cayenne Dashboard. 
  * Which means that you can control the value of vPin6 from the Cayenne app.
  */
 CAYENNE_IN(V6){
   vPin6 = getValue.asInt();
 }

 /*=CAYENNE_IN(V7) function====================================================================================================================================================== 
  * This will update the Arduino's vPin7 variable to the same value as Virtual Pin 7 on the Cayenne Dashboard. 
  * Which means that you can control the value of vPin7 from the Cayenne app.
  */
 CAYENNE_IN(V7){
   vPin7 = getValue.asInt();
 }
```

I have also tried to modify it, seen below, but with no success.

```
     void loop(){
      Cayenne.run();                                          //Synchronise with the Cayenne Server


  if(vPin6&&!vPin7){                                      //Only progress if Virtual Pin 6 (Person detection) is ACTIVATED but ONLY when Virtual Pin 7 (Intruder alert) has NOT already been activated.
if(!keyMessagePlayed){                                //This ensures that the message is played only ONCE when a person has been detected.
 yield();
  playSong(1);                                        //Play the following message on the Grove MP3 player: "Place your keys on the mat"
  keyMessagePlayed=true;                              //keyMessagePlayed is changed to TRUE once the message has been played.
}
```

Comment: I do not think that it is a yield issue. ESP is not capable to run multiple tasks so as long as yield work for task priority switch, it should not be your issue.

Comment: I've done a quick reading and see that ESP also overrides yield. Here it says about yielding: 

    This is one of the most critical differences between the ESP8266 and a more classical Arduino microcontroller. The ESP8266 runs a lot of utility functions in the background – keeping WiFi connected, managing the TCP/IP stack, and performing other duties. Blocking these functions from running can cause the ESP8266 to crash and reset itself. To avoid these mysterious resets, avoid long, blocking loops in your sketch.

Comment: Still I do not believe that this is a yield issue. Should be related with your libraries, memory, not execution.

Comment: i have also tried to run the simple cayenne connect code.which runs without problems on an esp8266-01.
the esp8266-201 still keeps restarting itself.is it faulty?my connections are:
vcc and ch_en to 3.3V,pin15 and gnd to gnd.still no success.

Comment: maybe you can remove your lib calls one by one and see which one causes the reset. Especially give a try to loop() lines.

Comment: i have tried also this code:


//#define CAYENNE_DEBUG         // Uncomment to show debug messages
#define CAYENNE_PRINT Serial  // Comment this out to disable prints and save space
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
#include "CayenneDefines.h"
#include "CayenneWiFiClient.h""



// Cayenne authentication token. This should be obtained from the Cayenne Dashboard.
char token[] = "";
// Your network name and password.
char ssid[] = "";
char password[] = "";

void setup()
{
 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Cayenne.begin(token, ssid, password);
}

void loop()
{
  Cayenne.run();
}

Comment: still no luck..

Comment: Don't you able to install Cayenne library via Manage Libraries from IDE?

Comment: I 've installed cayenne library properly..but even if I only run the simple cayenne connect sketch,it is still restarting itself.

Comment: the problem appears to be the serial calling..i deleted it and it works now for 6-7 hours without a single restart..it may be fixed..i really hope it will be ok now.i 'll try to add the controllers and i 'll post again if it solved the problem or not.

Comment: Maybe assigned pins have some other purposes then tx rx. Good to check pin map of your esp version.

Answer (score 0):

Not mentioned yet in the comments is the need of a decoupling / support capacitor of at least 0.1uF.

I was facing eventually resets using micro python and its webrepl. After I have added a 10uF Ceramic capacitor directly across the ESP Vcc and Gnd Pin everything works perfectly fine.

Remember the ESP doesn't only consume the 180mA peak current of the chip itself. The flash also consumes high currents on peaks.

Also discussed here: http://internetofhomethings.com/homethings/?p=396

Edit:
Here is a Photo of my ESP-12F. All my ESP have these capacitors connected even the ESP-01

[image: ESP12-F with 10uF]

Comment: I didn't have any capacitors connected..following an online tutorial i had every pin directly connected to vcc or gnd.so do you suggest adding a capacitor between vcc and gnd?can you send me a photo of your connections?just to be sure I 'll do all of the connections correctly..